# SQL Server 2016: Numbers Wildcard [^0-9] - filter out 0000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-server-2016

I'm using a wildcard for a 4-char field to filter out non-number values, which works OK, however I would also like to filter out '0000' values. Is it possible w/o using `'AND/OR'`?

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(4) = '0000'

SELECT  
    (CASE
        WHEN @D NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
           THEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(@D, 2))
           ELSE NULL 
     END)
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the extra parameter with an `AND`.

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(4) = '0000'

SELECT (CASE WHEN @D NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND @D != '0000' 
         THEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(@D, 2))
         ELSE NULL END)
```

Working example.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN yourfield NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND yourfield != '0000' 
       THEN 'xxx'
       ELSE NULL END
FROM yourtable
```

Input

```
1234
abcd
ab12
0000
9999
```

Output

```
xxx
(null)
(null)
(null)
xxx
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b0e4/1/0

Without needing `AND`/`OR`.

```
SELECT yourfield, 
CASE WHEN 0 = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REPLACE(yourfield,'0000','aaaa'))
     THEN 'xxx'
     ELSE NULL 
END AS filtered
FROM yourtable
```

Output

```
yourfield filtered
1234      xxx
abcd      (null)
ab12      (null)
0000      (null)
9999      xxx
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b0e4/45/0

Comment: thanks for your answer. i was hoping to find a wildcard/regex solution w/o having to use `AND/OR`

Comment: @Tsar Added additional answer that doesn't need `AND`/`OR`.

Comment: interestingly execution plans are same, which one should i pick?

Comment: @Tsar how big is the data set?

Comment: 500K rows and this check is done twice per row - selecting LEFT(@D, 2) & RIGHT(@D, 2)

Comment: Are either of the solutions too slow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156932/discussion-between-tsar-and-matt).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `LIKE` or `CASE` at all:

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(4) = '0000';
SELECT LEFT(TRY_CAST(NULLIF(@D, '0000') AS INT),2)+0;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EZYT8517)**

---

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT s.d,LEFT(TRY_CAST(NULLIF(s.d, '0000') AS INT),2)+0
FROM (SELECT '0000' UNION SELECT '12ab' UNION SELECT '1234') s(d);
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/YPLBR28873)**

Output:

```
0000    NULL
1234    12
12ab    NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This will output NULL for '0000':

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(4) = '0000'

SELECT  (CASE WHEN @D NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
             THEN CONVERT(INT, LEFT(NULLIF(@D, '0000'), 2))
             ELSE NULL
         END)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note:
1. ELSE NULL is redundant in a CASE statement; NULL is the default
2. If you're only returning two positive digits, you don't need int; tinyint would be fine.

Here's a couple other ways:

**Technique 1**

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(4) = '1x234'

SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@D)+CHARINDEX('0000',@D)=0 
        THEN CONVERT(tinyint, LEFT(@D, 2)) 
  END
```

**Technique 2**

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, LEFT(@D, 2)))
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@D)+CHARINDEX('0000',@D) = 0
```